# Create product bundle by matching user input to product features recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion, recommendation-engine

I am working on a Product Bundle creation and recommendation project. The bundling and recommendation have to happen in real-time based on user input.

The conditions are that
1.The product bundle should be such that it covers the user inputs as much as possible. 2. And there should be less duplication of user inputs across the recommends items.

```
user_input=['a','b','c']

d1=['a','c','d']
d2=['a','b','e','f']
d3=['a','c','b','f']
d4=['b']
d5=['g','e','a']
d6=['g']

expected output - d1 + d4, d3, d1+d2,d5+d4+d1
```

Following is my code, it gives results but it shows duplicate results and also doesn't show all the combinations. Any help is appreciated.

```
dlist=[d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6]
diff_match=[]
# find match n diff of each product based on user input
for i in range(len(dlist)):
    match=set(user_input).intersection(set(dlist[i]))
    #print("match is",match)
    diff=set(user_input).difference(set(dlist[i]))
    #print("diff is",diff)
    temp={'match':match,'diff':diff}
    diff_match.append(temp)
    
for i in range(len(diff_match)):
    # if match is found, recommend the product alone
    diff_match_temp=diff_match[i]['match']
    print("diff match temp is",diff_match_temp)
    if diff_match_temp==user_input:
        print ("absolute match")
    #scenario where the user input is subset of product features, seperate from partial match
    elif (all(x in list(diff_match_temp) for x in list(user_input))):
        print("User input subset of product features")
        print("The parent list is",diff_match[i]['match'])
        print("the product is", dlist[i])
    else:
        '''else check if the difference between user input and the current product is fulfilled by other product, 
        if yes, these products are bundled together'''
        for j in range(len(diff_match)):
            temp_diff=diff_match[i]['diff']
            print("temp_diff is",temp_diff)
            # empty set should be explicitly checked to avoid wrong match
            if (temp_diff.intersection(diff_match[j]['match'])==temp_diff and len(temp_diff)!=0 and list(temp_diff) != user_input) :
            #if temp_diff==diff_match[j]['match'] and len(temp_diff)!=0 and list(temp_diff) != user_input :
                print("match found with another product")
                print("parent is",dlist[i])
                print("the combination is",dlist[j] )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it recursively, you could create a function that returns the product with the largest component coverage and recurses to complete the bundles with the remaining components:

```
def getBundles(C,P):
    cSet     = set(C) # use set operations,  largest to smallest coverage
    coverage = sorted(P.items(),key=lambda pc:-len(cSet.intersection(pc[1])))
    for i,(p,cs) in enumerate(coverage):
        if cSet.isdisjoint(cs):continue          # no coverage
        if cSet.issubset(cs): yield [p];continue # complete (stop recursion)
        remaining = cSet.difference(cs)   # remaining components to bundle
        unused    = dict(coverage[i+1:])  # products not already bundled
        yield from ([p]+rest for rest in getBundles(remaining,unused))
```

output:

```
prods = {"d1":['a','c','d'],
         "d2":['a','b','e','f'],
         "d3":['a','c','b','f'],
         "d4":['b'],
         "d5":['g','e','a'],
         "d6":['g']}

user_input=['a','b','c']

for bundle in getBundles(user_input,prods):
    print(bundle)

['d3']
['d1', 'd2']
['d1', 'd4']
```

*Note that redundant combinations such as ['d5','d1','d2'] are excluded because d1+d2 covers everything that d5 covers and more, so d5 is redundant.  Permutations of the same products are also excluded (e.g. d1+d2 is the same as d2+d1)*

**[EDIT]**

If you need to offer redundant combinations (maybe as an extended selection option), you can write a slightly different recursive function that won't exclude them.  You should also sort the result in order of closest fit when presenting them:

```
def getBundles(C,P,remain=None,bundle=None):
    cSet  = set(C)                               # use set operations
    if remain is None: remain,bundle = cSet,[]   # track coverage & budle
    prods = list(P.items())                      # remaining products
    for i,(p,cs) in enumerate(prods):
        if cSet.isdisjoint(cs):continue         # no coverage
        newBundle = bundle+[p]                  # add product to bundle
        if remain.issubset(cs): yield newBundle # full coverage bundle 
        toCover = remain.difference(cs)         # not yet covered 
        unused  = dict(prods[i+1:])             # remainin products
        yield from getBundles(C,unused,toCover,newBundle) # recurse for rest
```

output:

```
prods = {"d1":['a','c','d'],
         "d2":['a','b','e','f'],
         "d3":['a','c','b','f'],
         "d4":['b'],
         "d5":['g','e','a'],
         "d6":['g']}    
user_input=['a','b','c']

for bundle in sorted(getBundles(user_input,prods),
                     key=lambda b:sum(map(len,(prods[p] for p in b)))):
    print(bundle)

['d1', 'd4']
['d3']
['d3', 'd4']
['d1', 'd2']
['d1', 'd3']
['d1', 'd4', 'd5']
['d3', 'd5']
['d1', 'd2', 'd4']
['d1', 'd3', 'd4']
['d2', 'd3']
['d3', 'd4', 'd5']
['d2', 'd3', 'd4']
['d1', 'd2', 'd5']
['d1', 'd3', 'd5']
['d1', 'd2', 'd3']
['d1', 'd2', 'd4', 'd5']
['d1', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5']
['d2', 'd3', 'd5']
['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']
['d2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5']
['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd5']
['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5']
```

Comment: thanks a ton for your answer. What if I want to have ['d5','d1','d2'] also? I might have to show this option also if say the cost or location is better suited to customer needs in this case.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a simple change I could make to include these redundant combinations while still excluding permutations.  A different set of conditions/recursion would likely be needed.

Comment: that shows too much redundancy though. I am wondering if we can have a flag like best match and redundant matches.

Comment: You could use two functions (one for best matches and one for redundant ones) but, in order not to get too many redundant combinations, an additional condition would be needed such as a limit on how many duplicate components a fully redundant product is allowed to have.  (I would suggest posting a new question for that).